# compute average over a list in python, excluding literals

Tags: python, list, average, literals, mean

In Python, I have a list of lists like the following:

```
[[1,2,3, 'L'], ['L'], [1]]
```

and I want to compute for each sublist the average over all the numerical elements. Values 'L' should thus be excluded. The result for the above example should be:

```
[2, [], 1]
```

Is there any quick way of doing this in one line?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you specifically want one line, or just shortest possible?  I'm pretty sure you can't do that in one line, just because there are at least 2 or 3 distinct high-level operations you have to complete.

Comment: As short as possible works! I just wanted to have a smarter way of doing this than iterating over the each sublist, checking whether it's not an 'L', incrementing counters and sums, etc.

Comment: Why the result is `[2, [], 1]` not `[2, 0, 1]` ?

Comment: @Zoozy: The average over an empty list is undefined, not 0.  I'd probably use `None` or `float("nan")` as the undefined value.

Comment: @sr2222 You can do it in one line but I'm pretty sure the OP would not want that!

Comment: I just need a symbol to tell apart lists with non numerical values. In practice, 0 would work because I'm dealing with packet delays and the average can't possibly be 0, but I think I'd better use a literal. Or maybe not?

Comment: @jamylak, Well, sure, with a couple nested list comprehensions, I suppose... but man would it be ugly.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought there was some quick and elegant way to do this, but if it's not the case, I'd rather go for some code that is longer but easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a highly unreadable one-liner, assuming you've already imported `numpy` and `numbers`.  Lists with no numeric elements show up as `nan` in the resulting list.

```
[numpy.mean([x for x in sublist if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]) for sublist in mainlist]
```

Answer (score 11):

To get the exact result you asked for, I would do this:

```
from __future__ import division
import numbers
def average_over_numeric_values(a):
    filtered = [x for x in a if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
    if filtered:
        return sum(filtered) / len(filtered)
    return []
print(map(average_over_numeric_values, list_of_lists))
```

This is not exactly a one-liner, but a quite readable way.

Personally, I wouldn't use `[]` as a result if there are no empty values in the list – `None` seems more suitable.

Comment: Isn't `if len(filtered)` the same functionality under the covers as `if filtered`, which is more concise?

Comment: `return np.mean(filtered) if filtered else []`

Comment: `sum([]) == 0` so `0` is a more consistent choice.

Comment: @wim: Using NumPy, I'd just do `numpy.mean(filtered)`, which returns `nan` for an empty input.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The average would be `sum([])/len([])`, which is undefined, not zero.

Comment: +1 for the elegant answer, but perhaps add `import numbers`?  I had to open a console to confirm that `numbers` is not defined by default.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: you're right. `0/0` is better represented by `float('nan')`.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
x = [[1,2,3, 'L'], ['L'], [1]]
```

If you must have a one-liner:

```
[sum(w)/float(len(w)) if w else w for w in [[z for z in y if isinstance(z, numbers.Number)] for y in x]]
```